# How do you reset your account's camouflages and prestiges?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

How can you restart your Black Ops 2 completely, so that you still have all the things you bought for the game, but reset the account's weapons, camouflages and prestiges?

Answer (score 0):

In CoD: Ghosts, when you reach max prestige (10th) you have the option to reset. I am not sure if this is the same in CoD: BO2.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter prestige mode in Black Ops II, your level is reset, and you are awarded a **Prestige Token**. From prestige levels 1 - 10 the **Prestige Token** can be traded in for one of three rewards, after which your token is revoked.

The rewards are as follows:

- Unlock an extra Custom Class slot
- Refund all your regular Unlock Tokens used during the current prestige
- Reset all of your progress (This will wipe all stats, inlcuding challenge progress and calling cards and camouflages.)

After prestige level 10 you can prestige into **Prestige Master**, which will unlock all weapons and class slots. At this level you the only reward you may choose is to reset all of your progress.

To reset all of your stats, navigate into the **Barracks** menu. From there you can you can scroll down to **Prestige Mode** and select **Prestige Awards**. Simply choose the **Reset** award, and all of your progress will be wiped.